# byfn.sh fails with binaries and docker images out of sync

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Following the [build your first network tutorial on hyperledger docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html) when I type

```
$ ./byfn.sh up
```

I get following warning

```
LOCAL_VERSION=1.2.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.1
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are  
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.       
===============================================
```

and finally the script fails with this error

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the bootstrap process by `cd`ing into the folder `fabric-samples/scripts` and run `bootstrap.sh` again like this

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh
```

This made my images to get synced like this in the output

```
LOCAL_VERSION=1.3.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first delete the existing and then download the higher version of Hyperledger Fabric. You can run the following commands to do this:

```sh
cd fabric-samples
rm -Rf bin
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.3.0
./scripts/bootstrap.sh
```