# Local fabric-ca binaries and docker images are out of sync (raspberry pi)

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am using raspberry pi and I follow the instruction on Deployment of Hyperledger Fabric on ARM64 architecture (https://githubmemory.com/repo/maciejjedrzejczyk/hlf-arm64). But I got this message always saying "Local fabric-ca binaries and docker images are out of sync. This may cause problems.". When I run "**./network.sh up -ca**", this is what I get.

*Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' with crypto from 'Certificate Authorities'

LOCAL_VERSION=2.4.1

DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.4.1

CA_LOCAL_VERSION=1.5.2

CA_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=

Local fabric-ca binaries and docker images are out of sync. This may cause problems.
Generating certificates using Fabric CA

Starting ca_org1    ... done

Starting ca_orderer ... done

Starting ca_org2    ... done*

It will stuck here and not proceed.
can anyone help me? please

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791899/byfn-sh-fails-with-binaries-and-docker-images-out-of-sync

Comment: I can't go and run bootstrap.sh directly on Raspberry Pi (ARM64 architecture).